Iterating through Rscript code sections with a for loop
I have an RScript file, which consist of 28 sections, which each one define seven variables named identically. Example:
# SECTION 1 ######
variable1 <- numericalvalue1  
variable2 <- numericalvalue2
. . . (etc) 
variable7 <- numericalvalue7

# SECTION 2 ######
variable1 <- someothernumericalvalue1
variable2 <- someothernumericalvalue2
. . . (etc)
variable7 <- someothernumericalvalue7

. . . (etc etc etc) 

# SECTION 28 ######

variable1 <- someothernumericalvalueX
variable2 <- someothernumericalvalueY
. . . (etc)
variable7 <- someothernumericalvalueZ

After these different setups for the values of the variables, each section needs to be run with a part that is common for all of them. This last part basically draws a ggplot using the values set in each of the sections, which will mean that it produces 28 plots.
my_plot <- ggplot() +
  geom_point() +
  geom_circle(aes(x0=2, y0=2, r=2), fill=variable1) + 
  geom_circle(aes(x0=2, y0=2, r=2), fill=variable2) + 
  geom_circle(aes(x0=2, y0=2, r=2), fill=variable3) + 
  coord_fixed()

png(filename="MyPlot_iteration1.png")
my_plot
graphics.off()

The thing is that it can get burdensome to manually highlight each section, and then run the rest of the code, plus also manually naming each saved file with the section number. Especially if there would be 280 sections instead of the 28 that I have now.
So my question is: Is there a way to create a for loop that could iterate through the sections in the same Rscript file?
In my python-oriented mind it should be something like:
#this is just something to illustrate the idea
for x in range(1,29):
     for section x:
           run section x
           run the common plotting part
           save with a name that has the format MyPlot_x.png

Is this achievable with R, preferrably Base R?
Thank you very much in advance!

Could you make a table with something like data.frame(section = 1:28, variable1 = c(numericalvalue1, someothernumericalvalue1, someothernumericalvalueX, ... ), variable2 = c(.....  )) then you could loop through the sections to make your plots. Or you could construct it one section at a time like data.frame(section = 1, ....) |> bind_rows(data.frame(section = 2, ....)). Whether a data frame or a list, having the variables bundled in one object would make this simpler.

@JonSpring Thank you for your answer! This seems like a good way.
Could it also work just like:
variable1 <- c(value1, value2 .... value28)
variable2 <- c(value1, value2 .... value28)
.....
variable28 <- c(value1, value2 .... value28)
and then looping through these with the indexes? Something like:
for x in range(1,28): variable1[x]

@JonSpring I'm guessing now that making a table is the R way to look at this.
I'd like to accept your answer as the solution for my question but can't find a way to do so. Thank you again and have a nice week!

I think the important thing from a workflow and maintenance perspective is to put them together in a way that is clear and easy for the human, preferably bound in a list or table or set of vectors like you describe, so that then you just instruct the code to iterate through a same-shaped thing each time. It's generally good practice in my experience to keep things that are used together in one object. e.g. an orthogonal example: https://www.tjmahr.com/lists-knitr-secret-weapon/
